# How to generate hierarchy with json and php?

Tags: php, json, hierarchy

How to generate a hierarchy with `json` and `php` like the image below?

[image]

Comment: make array of child array then convert it to json.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Array:

```
$arr = array(
    "X1" => array(
        "X2" => array("X4", "X5"),
        "X3" => array("X6", "X7")
    )
);
```

JSON Encode:

```
echo $json = json_encode($arr); //{"X1":{"X2":["X4","X5"],"X3":["X6","X7"]}}
```